# Run Azure's Document Intelligence Studio container

Tags: docker, sqlite, azure-cognitive-services

We want to run Form Recognizer [Document Intelligence Studio](https://mcr.microsoft.com/product/azure-cognitive-services/form-recognizer/studio/tags) from the container.

According to the documentation, the valid approach could be:

> docker run --rm -it -p 5000:5000 --memory 30g --cpus 5 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/form-recognizer/studio:latest Eula=accept Billing=https://docintelinxxxxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com ApiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

We tried this approach for the [Read model](https://mcr.microsoft.com/product/azure-cognitive-services/form-recognizer/read-3.0/tags), and it worked great. But for the Studio command ends with:

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionInternal..ctor(SqliteConnectionStringBuilder connectionOptions, SqliteConnectionPool pool)
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionPool.GetConnection()
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionFactory.GetConnection(SqliteConnection outerConnection)
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()
> at  . . (IServiceCollection , IConfiguration )
> at  . . (String[] )

How do we handle this SQLite problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/containers/install-run?view=doc-intel-3.0.0&tabs=read), `studio` is not supported as direct service through container.

To use Form Recognizer [Document Intelligence Studio](https://mcr.microsoft.com/product/azure-cognitive-services/form-recognizer/studio/tags) from the container, you can use disconnect container with any of the supported `service`.
Also, you need to provide `STORAGE_DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING` to connect with your database.

```yaml
studio:
  container_name: form-recognizer-studio
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/form-recognizer/studio:3.0
  environment:
    ONPREM_LOCALFILE_BASEPATH: /onprem_folder
    STORAGE_DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING: /onprem_db/Application.db
  volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: ${FILE_MOUNT_PATH} # path to your local folder
      target: /onprem_folder
    - type: bind
      source: ${DB_MOUNT_PATH} # path to your local folder
      target: /onprem_db
  ports:
    - "5001:5001"
  user: "1000:1000" # echo $(id -u):$(id -g)
```

For more details and example, you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/containers/disconnected?view=doc-intel-3.0.0#run-the-container-in-a-disconnected-environment).